# Display PopupWindow upon clicking a button?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, illegalstateexception, android-popupwindow

Currently, I have a button, within a `Linear Layout`, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/open_popup"
        android:onClick="createPopup"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also have a createPopup extension (which does indeed execute when the button is clicked).

```
public void createPopup(View view) {

}
```

I have tried to create a `PopupWindow` with a `TextView` within it. I then called `showAtLocation(parent, gravity, x, y)` where `parent` is the root `LinearLayout`. `gravity` was `Gravity.BOTTOM`, `x` and `y` were both set to `10`.

When I clicked the button, I received an `IllegalStateException` error where I called `showAtLocation()`. Here is the `createPopup()` function:

```
PopupWindow popUp;
LinearLayout layout;
LinearLayout main;
TextView value;
LayoutParams params;
boolean click = true;
public void createPopup(View view) {
    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    value = new TextView(this);
    if(click) {
        popUp.showAtLocation(main, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
        popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
        click = false;
    } else {
        popUp.dismiss();
        click = true;
    }
    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    value.setText(R.string.message);
    layout.addView(value, params);
    popUp.setContentView(layout);
    setContentView(main);
    TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    status.setTextSize(28);
    status.setText("Status of Popup: Don't worry, you're never going to get this.");
}
```

What I would like to know is:

- What does that error mean?
- Why does it appear?
- How can I fix it?
- How do I create a simple popup window that appears at the click of a button?*

*I'd like to be able to create a function where it takes at least one parameter (which would be a `String`), and then create's a popup window that contains that `String`, as well as a button to close the popup window.

**EDIT**: Not sure if this is connected to the popup issue, but when I run the app, I get this error:

```
07-13 19:51:48.448 133-133/? E/[EGL-ERROR]: egl_image* _egl_create_image_ANDROID_native_buffer(egl_display*, egl_context*, EGLClientBuffer, EGLint*, void*):593: CHUN try create image with crop 0,0,0,0


                                            [ 07-13 19:51:48.448   133:  133 E/         ]
                                            CHUN map external image rgb 1024 x 600
```

**SECOND EDIT:** I've added relevant code above.

Comment: post the full stacktrace of the error. including the error message, that is important.

Comment: I don't know if I will be able to reproduce it, but I can try.

Comment: Please make sure to five full stacktraces when giving an error its incredibly helpful for understanding what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at how to implement a Dialog, what I normally do is create a separate layout file, class file, and call it from where it needs to be shown. Dialogs show over the other activity in the center, and as far as I know, they cannot be moved.

When you want to show the dialog, you can call:

```
private void openMyDialog() {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this);
    dialog.show();
}
```

MyDialog.java needs to extend `Dialog` and implement `android.view.View.OnClickListener`. It will contain any code necessary to save or control the elements on your layout.
MyDialog.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity activity;

    public MyDialog() {
        super(null);
    }
    public MyDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }

}
```

my_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1C1C1C">
<!-- Whatever your layout will consist of can go here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this answers your question. If it does not, feel free to comment on this post. I do not know how to fix your error (as it is not the full error) but I do know how to implement custom Dialogs (or Popups) to go over your other activity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying your solution, and then I'll go back and look at the details of how it works in the docs. Could you add the import statements that you are using?

Comment: I think I pasted all the necessary ones... I copied this out of a large file that has a bunch of other imports for other things that you won't need. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: On about line 18, it says `this.activity = activity`. Android Studio is telling me that it couldn't be resolved. Did you mean to do `this.setOwnerActivity(activity)`?

Comment: No... I accidentally deleted a line when I was copying/pasting... I changed it in the code. It was supposed to have a `public Activity activity;` declared at the top.